# Count number of records open on date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working in **Excel 2007**.

I have a list of policies, with a date they were received and a date the work on them was closed out.

For example:

```
Policy Open Date Close Date
1      1/1/14    1/14/14
2      2/1/14    2/13/14
3      1/10/14   3/3/14
```

etc.

I need to know how many records were open each day of the year. How many were open on 1/1, how many on `1/2`, etc.

I'm having trouble getting a simple countifs formula to work. Any ideas?

Comment: what did you try? are you storing dates as date-values or as text?

Comment: I am using date values.

I am not set on the correct method of counting yet. If I am looking for a count for 1/1/14, then the open date should be <= 1/1/14 and the close date should be > 1/1/14, right?

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on what time of day the policies were opened and closed, e.g. if closed at noon it would still be open for part of that day, if at midnight the previous night then it would be closed all day?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that policies are valid for at least part of the open date and the close date so I will suggest <= 1/1/14 and >=1/1/14 for the first date. But you would have to read the small print.

Enter the first date in (say) E2 and pull it down to produce the calendar dates.

Then put the COUNTIFS formula in F2 and pull it down:-

```
=COUNTIFS(B$2:B$4,"<="&E2,C$2:C$4,">="&E2)
```

Then it will look like this (my dates are in UK format) :-

[image]